# how to provide tcp/ssl support on the same port

Tags: ssl, tcp, erlang

Le'ts say you open a tcp socket on port 80 to handle http request, and a ssl socket on port 443 to deal with https...how can some proxy provide access to both of them on the same port??

I found only this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327850/support-both-ssl-and-non-ssl-on-the-same-server-port) but it wasn't very useful. Can you provide me an erlang example or suggest me some resources from which i can learn more on the topic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, was your question about "port unification" (running two different types of servers on the same port) or how an HTTP proxy can handle requests for both HTTP and HTTPS servers?

Comment: well...i would be interested in both cases you pointed out (i'm trying to learn as much as i can on this kind of topics)..thanks

Comment: Port unification is much less common, but it relies on looking at the incoming packet to see which protocol it should handle (@seb's answer). An HTTP proxy doesn't really relay the HTTP requests when using HTTPS, instead, it forwards the entire TCP connection to the HTTPS server (so the SSL/TLS layer is established directly between the browser and the target server), after the client has used `CONNECT` (@MattH's answer).

Comment: thanks Bruno, you have been really helpful :)

Comment: In case it is useful for others who come across this question, [here is an implementation of port unification using Jetty in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24891007/394431).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As outlined in the link you provide, you will need to write your own custom server that sniffs the request and then redirects to the correct protocol accordingly.

As http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2818.html indicates, an HTTP session will start with an Initial Request Line (e.g. `GET /`), whereas a TLS session will start with a ClientHello (more on the TLS session on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake_in_detail))

There are lots of resources online about writing servers in Erlang, e.g. [How to write a simple webserver in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206933/how-to-write-a-simple-webserver-in-erlang)

Incidentally your terminology is incorrect: http, https SSL and TLS are *protocols*, and all operate (over the web) using TCP sockets.

Answer (score 5):

> how can some proxy provide access to both of them on the same port??

By implementing the HTTP `CONNECT` method, the (non-transparent) proxy may switch to providing a TCP tunnel over which a browser may, for example, access an HTTPS resource.

A rather sparse specification:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.9